# Jsdom throwing error for some URLs

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom

I am new to nodejs, what I'm trying to do is to scan all the url of my site (with javascript and jquery enabled) and check that the url contains a given string.

To do this I'm using jsdom, but when I launch the script extracts only some url and then crashes giving this error:

```
timers.js:110
    first._onTimeout();
          ^
TypeError: Property '_onTimeout' of object [object Object] is not a function
at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
```

Surely there is something wrong but I don't understand where..

This is my script:

```
var request = require('request');
var jsdom = require('jsdom');

request({ uri: 'http://www.example.com' }, function (error, response, html) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

     var doc = jsdom.jsdom(html, null, {
           features: {
              FetchExternalResources   : ['script'],
              ProcessExternalResources : ['script'],
              MutationEvents           : '2.0',
           }
     });

     var window = doc.createWindow();
     jsdom.jQueryify(window, "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js", function() {
        var $ = window.jQuery;
        $('a').each(function(i, element){
             var a = $(this).attr('href');
             console.log(a);
             if (a.indexOf('string') != -1) {
               console.log('The winner: '+a);
               //return a;
             }
        });
        window.close();
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but only on some urls. I haven't yet determined if it's an error thrown by the actual execution of scripts in the scraped html, or if it's an internal error in the jsdom code. Signs point to both right now :)

Comment: I made a pull request as per @faridNouriNeshat 's advice : https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/pull/1186

Answer (score 3):

This is because of somewhere in your page they are calling setTimeout/setInterval with a string that is not supported in node and it results in that error.

To find out where is it coming from, I suggest just require [longjohn](https://github.com/mattinsler/longjohn) module(`require('longjohn')`) and you get long stack traces, which they will help you to find the error. For example I got something like this from doing this in the repl:

```
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:110:15)
---------------------------------------------
    at startTimer (/home/alfred/repos/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/index.js:75:15)
    at DOMWindow.setTimeout (/home/alfred/repos/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/index.js:124:50)
    at file:///home/alfred/repos/repl:undefined:undefined<script>:1:1
    at Contextify.sandbox.run (/home/alfred/repos/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/lib/contextify.js:12:24)
    at exports.javascript (/home/alfred/repos/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/level2/languages/javascript.js:5:14)
    at define.proto._eval (/home/alfred/repos/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/level2/html.js:1523:47)
    at /home/alfred/repos/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/level2/html.js:76:20
    at item.check (/home/alfred/repos/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/level2/html.js:345:11)
```

If by any chance that didn't work for you or you didn't like it, then I suggest you to modify this jsdom file: node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/index.js, function startTimer. Throw an error there if the `callback` wasn't a function. This will throw whenever offending code was run.

In case if you are running code that you can't change(like from websites you don't own, which I don't suggest it because foreign javascript like that could be used to attack your app), you could override DOMWindow.setTimeout/.setInterval to support string arguments. You could also make open an issue for jsdom to have this opt-in.